# cannot delete sql row using php

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me deleting the user data from sql table when the user logs out?

My logout file is:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();
include('config.php');
require_once('delete.php');

//Unset the variables stored in session
unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);?>
```

The delete file required at the beginning is supposed to replace the user values with empty values, since i cannot delete them, also...

The delete file is this:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

include('config.php');

$login= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

mysql_query("UPDATE registo SET username='' AND password='' WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'");
{
    echo "Deleted Successfully";
}?>
```

Please help!

Comment: 1st syntax error after SET you must separate with , .
2nd mysql_ functions are deprecated in newest PHP version so use either mysqli or PDO.
3rd you don't escape at all the input posts and anyone can inject your database...

Comment: You're including `config.php` twice and setting `session_start()` twice.

Comment: And what is the { } after mysql_query for? Do you get any errors?

Comment: **Your code is incredibly insecure and a simply string can destroy ALL of your users because you inject SQL**. `username=' OR 1 = 1 --`. That's all it takes and suddenly **all of your users** will have no username and no password. It's like you meant for this to be a great example of why SQL injections are so critical.

Comment: You say you want to *delete* stuff. Your code is in `delete.php`. SQL has a `DELETE` statement. But you use `UPDATE`... Is it intentional? (You also print `Deleted Successfully` no matter the result of your code.)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the `UPDATE` clause is this:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

That is to say, you provide a comma separated list of columns.

You have this:

```
UPDATE registo
SET username='' AND password=''
```

No commas, so you're telling MySQL to update only one column: `username`. And the new value is `'' AND password=''`. That's zero:

```
mysql> SELECT '' AND password='' FROM registo;
+--------------------+
| '' AND password='' |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thus your code equals:

```
UPDATE registo
SET username=0
```

You possibly mean this:

```
UPDATE registo
SET username=NULL, password=NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fro your comment, but i'll try to be more specific: